# SObject constructor must use name=value pairs

Tags: apex, visualforce

This is a custom object. this is the error 
Compile Error: SObject constructor must use name=value pairs at line 8 column 22

```
public list<student__c> myStud = new list<student__c>();
List<student__c> stud_qry = new List<student__c>();
public list<student__c> stud()
{
     stud_qry =  [select Id, First_Name__c, name from Student__c];  
     for(student__c getEm : stud_qry)
     {
        myStud.add(new student__c(getEm.first_name__c+' ' + getEm.name));
     }
     return myStud;
}
```

Comment: Gelay is My ans making any sense let me know

Comment: yes but i have another error

Comment: What is the error.

Comment: Invalid selectOptions found. Use SelectOption type in Apex.

Comment: Pls don't update this ans instead ask another question else evryone think my ans is different and they will give me downvote

Comment: okay..... ill reverse it

Comment: I have already created a new question. how can i tag u @Ratan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Error in this line**

```
myStud.add(new student__c(getEm.first_name__c+' ' + getEm.name));
```

this should be name value pair.

```
myStud.add(new student__c(Name = getEm.first_name__c+' ' + getEm.name));
```

You need to specify Field API name and respective value like this `Name = getEm.first_name__c+' ' + getEm.name`